# Using Textblobbed in sqlite-net-extensions

Tags: c#, json, sqlite, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm trying to map a complex class in sqlite but something seems to be wrong because when I retrieve my objects the complex fields are empty.
Shortly, my class is something similar:

```
 public class Contact
 {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }

    [TextBlob("PhoneNumbersBlobbed")]
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { set; get; }
    public string PhoneNumbersBlobbed { get; set; } // serialized PhoneNumbers

    [TextBlob("MailAddressesBlobbed")]
    public List<ContactEmail> MailAddresses { set; get; }
    public string MailAddressesBlobbed { get; set; } // serialized MailAddresses
 }
```

I obviously have a separated class for PhoneNumber:

```
     public class PhoneNumber
     {          
        public string Number { set; get; }
        public bool IsVerified { set; get; }
        public string AttrString { set; get; }  
    }
```

while ContactEmail class is a native class of WinPhone.

Well, after have created the tables in DB:

```
 connection.CreateTable<Contact.PhoneNumber>();
 connection.CreateTable<Contact>();
```

and have populated my List of Contact I save them in DB. I tried as saving one by one with:

```
connection.InsertWithChildren(contact,true);
```

as all the list togheter:

```
connection.InsertAllWithChildren(listOfContacts, true);
```

and I'm sure that the list is correctly populated before to save it.
But when I read its values from sqlite:

```
var list = connection.Table<Contact>().ToList();
connection.UpdateAll(list ,true);
```

I can't see values in my PhoneNumbers and MailAddresses fields, while they are filled with serialized value in their blobbed fields.

In addiction, trying to manually deserialize the blobbed fields, I get an exception from Json.net (ie. doing in this way):

```
 foreach (Contact pc in list)
        {
            try
            {
                Contact.PhoneNumber[] numbs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhoneContact.PhoneNumber[]>(pc.PhoneNumbersBlobbed);
            }
            catch {
                ;
            }
        }
```

what am I wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In order to retrieve relationships from the database you have to use any of the `WithChildren` methods provided by SQLite-Net Extensions.

Try changing these lines:

```
var list = connection.Table<Contact>().ToList();
connection.UpdateAll(list ,true);
```

To this:

```
var list = connection.GetAllWithChildren<Contact>();
```

You won't need the `PhoneNumber` table either, because they are being serialized in the text property. So you can remove this line:

```
connection.CreateTable<Contact.PhoneNumber>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried to read values with the GetAllWithChildren method, it throw an exception via Json Deserializer. The exception message is `Error converting value "+393487373383" to type Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact `

Comment: Sounds like you saved a phone number ("+393487373383") in the `PhoneNumbersBlobbed` property and then you tried to deserialize it as a JSON. You shouldn't ever use `PhoneNumbersBlobbed` property directly.

Comment: No, I didn't used directly the blobbed field, I simply declared as required the complex object decored by its blobbed string field and saved all the list as writed in the first post.